# Encountering TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to do a "jumbo command", but when I use the command I encounter the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "jumbo",
    description: "",
    execute(client, message, args) {
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Debes escribir un emoji.");

        let emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find((x) => x.name === args[0].split(":")[1]);

        if (!emoji) return message.channel.send("Ese no es un emoji válido.");

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("Emoji:").setImage(emoji.url).setColor("RANDOM");

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you execute your command?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Command handling page of the Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files), a well-formed exported module's `execute` method only has 2 arguments: `message`, and `args`. `client` does not appear to be supported as you seem to think it is. This is in line with `args` being undefined: no parameter at this position will be set and will thus be `undefined`, and would cause errors similar to/the same as the one you're currently encountering.

The aforementioned page specifically mentions how you can grab the instance of client for use in your code:

> ##### TIP
>
> If you need to access your client instance from inside one of your command files, you can access it via `message.client`. [...]

Comment: Aside, if you have an authoritative source upon which you're basing your understanding that `client` should be the first argument of three for `execute()` it would be helpful for you to link it in the body of your original question for everyone's understanding.